# Power BI - get the graph out of the data set

Tags: powerbi

It seems very simple but I can not get the graph to show the data I want.

So, I have got a lot of IDs with the end and start dates (LENGHT) and open items (OPEN). Each day has got availability (AVAIL) and there is nil used (USED) at day 1.

```
ID  LENGTH  OPEN    USED    AVAIL
1A  6       100     0       2400
```

I need to create the NEW_DAY column with count of the LENGHT. In this case the result would be

```
ID  LENGTH  NEW_DAY OPEN    USED    AVAIL
1A   6       1       100      0     2400
1A   6       2       100      0     2400
1A   6       3       100      0     2400
1A   6       4       100      0     2400
1A   6       5       100      0     2400
1A   6       6       100      0     2400
```

Note, I have hundreds of IDs so can not hard code it as 1A and needs to be dynamic.

Comment: do you mean `NEW_DAY` will be indexed per ID Group i.e if for ID 1B you have 10 Records you will have your last `NEW_DAY` as 10?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe this might help you.
If you add a blank query and add this expression:

```
= List.Repeat({1, 2}, 3)
```

you will get the first argument `{1, 2}` repeated three times.

When you separate your ID in a new column and pass this column to the code above (the same goes for the second argument) it might work.